# Can Load Balancer serve as web server instead of nginx for API-only flask app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask

I have a Flask app that should reside on EKS in a **core** + **workers** constellation, strictly  API, no front-end. **Core** processes the requests, and breaks down the tasks for **workers** to pick up, SNS and SQS involved. `gunicorn` will be used in **core** - **workers** are only  utilizing internal logic w/ DB reads/writes.

In most tutorials/examples I've seen `nginx` is also used. Do I really need it if I'll only use API access? Wouldn't Load Balancer serve the same purpose with the benefit of integrated logging?

I am trying to think of a simple yet robust architecture w/o overengineering the whole thing. I'd like to keep scalability options, might add Lambda layer and Redis for cache. Most of the scalability I'd need should be served by EKS, no?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Load Balancer rather than Nginx as long as flask is serving HTTP traffic that the load balancer can connect to.

In doing this you would lose out on any functionality that NGinx was originally providing. An ALB can only affect traffic flow between servers but not the configuration that exists on the server.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 'lost functionality'? As for configuration, I was thinking of  using ELB to point to **core**'s service layer only to make it highly available. Now that I think of it, I don't think I even need a Load Balancer for it, only publicly-facing service layer configuration on EKS.

Comment: All I meant is by not using Nginx any functionality you were reliant on might not necessarily be available in the ELB. If you simply just proxy all traffic to Flask then yes it will work :)

Comment: Thank you. This certainly solves the **simple** part. Will have to test it for the **robust** part as stuff develops.

Comment: No problem glad I could help, let me know if you have any further questions :)